# When the answer to a question may have changed is there a way to recommend a review?

Tags: support, feature-request, question-quality, answer-quality

The following question:
[Why does Captain Lorca care about scattered pockets of negative mass?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/175758/why-does-captain-lorca-care-about-scattered-pockets-of-negative-mass)

Was was asked mid-way through Discovery's first season.  Now that season one is over I'm wondering if there is anyway on the site to have this question reviewed?  I'm not saying the answer is right or wrong, but a lot more information is now known about the subject.  And I'm wondering about an answer to a question like this mid way through a season or a trilogy etc.

So should we have a way/Is there a way to say to the question author, are you still happy with the answer or should this now be reviewed?

Answer (score 13):

### To get an updated answer

There's a [bounty](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/bounty) reason for that:

[image: Screenshot of bounty popup]

### To get the OP to review acceptance

There's no certain or by-design way of doing this. Just ping them in a comment (assuming they're still an active user and likely to see your ping, which in this case the OP is).

Alternatively, if there's already an accepted answer and *not* a new answer reflecting recent updates, you could ping the existing answerer in a comment asking them to update their answer.

Comment: Super, thanks that answers my question, and make people invest in getting an answer updated.